# I still received my IP address with Tor when check client_ip via PHP

Tags: php, node.js, tor

I have node.js run on my PC and Im trying to visit my PHP site via Tor.

I got installed Tor on Mac , configured .. and ready to go:

- ✅ ControlPort
- ✅ HashedControlPassword
- ✅ HiddenServiceDir/HiddenServicePort
- ✅ RefreshTorSession per request
- ✅ torrc (config) is enabled

Here is my node.js script where I expect to hide my IP:

```
var tr = require('tor-request');
tr.TorControlPort.password = '****'
    tr.setTorAddress('localhost', 9050);
    
function run() {
    tr.newTorSession( (err) =>
    {
        requestIP();
        return;
    });
}

function requestIP() {
    tr.request({
       url: "https://api.ipify.org", // when change to my  PHP site.. IP still detected
        headers: {
            'user-agent': 'meo'
        }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("Your public (through Tor) IP is: " + body);
        } else {
            console.log('error ' + err);
        }
    })
}
run();
```

Here how I detect IP on PHP site:

```
function getRealIpAddr(){
 if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ) {
  // Check IP from internet.
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
 } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
  // Check IP is passed from proxy.
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
 } else {
  // Get IP address from remote address.
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 }
return $ip;
}
```

Check my sample node.js script and you will see I call api.ipify.org  .. results are expected(IP changed) . Problem when I try to reach my PHP site which stores IP visitor. I am using same node.js script .. I see that my real IP has been tracked there as list of IPs I think It's HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

> As it turns out, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can sometimes have a comma
> delimited list of IP addresses – so what we actually needed to be
> doing was take the last IP address in that list, before doing our
> conversion to an integer.

I need to fix this and hide my IP when calling my php via node.js with Tor network ..
Strangely when I call my PHP with Tor Browser, it works!!!
Is there any advanced setup on Tor to hide my IP completely?

Comment: Please clarify where what is running. You're requesting what from where and how are those two related network-wise?

Comment: @deceze updated .. I working on experimental task that I was trying to track / detect visitors who use Tor network .. so I created my Node.js Script ( caller) via Tor to my PHP site

Comment: Sorry but I can't make sense of your words. *"When I tried to call https://api.ipify.org .. I got IP changed"* So you are seeing another IP and that's what you expect, right? *"but in my site I got two IPs in this format myIP,anotherIP .. both fixed whatever I do .."* What does this mean? Is your site hosted on an external server? And it output two IP addresses? How is doing that? *"why still I can detect my IP"* I assume that means why does it print your client's original IP, not the Tor IP?

Comment: *"when I tried to call my PHP with Tor Browser . it works!!!"* I think you are saying that you using Tor standalone and Tor Browser and your site works as expected with Tor Browser but not if you are enabling standalone Tor and use a "normal" browser, is that correct?

Comment: well partially yes except that  Im not using (normal) browser .. I am making http request via tor network  with node.js

Comment: @FelixKling simply when I tried sample and call api.ipify.org  with Tor standalone .. I thought I succeed to hide my IP .. but when I tried to detect IP address of visitor on PHP site instead of api.ipify.org  I saw my real one .. clear now :) ?